# For loop traversal

Tags: c++, for-loop, int

Consider `A` as `vector<int>`

```
enter code here

int x,max;
for(x:A){
    if(x>max)
    max=x;
}
```

can anyone tell me why this is giving me error
this is the error:

```
solution.cpp:6:10: error: found ':' in nested-name-specifier, expected '::'

    for(x:A){
         ^
        ::

solution.cpp:6:9: error: 'x' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

    for(x:A){
```

The error is resolved once is declare `int x` inside the for loop
i.e. `for(int x :A)`
please resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post a [mre]

Comment: anyhow, thats simply not correct syntax for a range based for loop

Comment: To get the maximum element of a container, use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the suggestion. Can you suggest some me some good resource from where I can read more about such stl features.

Comment: @khemukaanmol https://cppreference.com and https://cplusplus.com

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (emphasis mine):

> `attr`(optional) `for` ( `range_declaration` : `range_expression` ) `loop_statement`
>
> [...]
>
> `range_declaration`   -   **a declaration of a named variable**, whose type is the type of the element of the sequence represented by range_expression, or a reference to that type. Often uses the auto specifier for automatic type deduction

Declaration of a variable is required for range-based loop syntax. You cannot use a variable from the outside (declared before the loop).

Comment: So it is because the range for loop is defined in that way or is there any other explanation to it that what was the reason to do so?

Comment: @khemukaanmol Yes, it's just defined this way ("The standard says so"). It's not a common use-case to reuse variables from the outside and it very rarely makes sense.  I assume allowing that would add extra work for the compilers, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @khemukaanmol it would be of little use, because the value of `x` from before the loop would not be accesible inside the loop and only the value from the last iteration would be accesible after the loop, but if you need that, there are cleaner ways

Answer (score 1):

[for ( range_declaration :](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

> range_declaration     -   a declaration of a named variable, whose type is the type of the element of the sequence represented by range_expression, or a reference to that type. Often uses the auto specifier for automatic type deduction

You'll need a fresh variable for a range-for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can not reuse a variable in the range-for loop. The left hand side of the colon must be a declaration:

Fixed version:

```
for(int x : A){
```

or just use `auto` keyword:

```
for (auto x : A)
```